# TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter

Как сделать такой TextformField в Flutter?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикрепите код, покажите что у вас уже есть, просить готовое решение - странно.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)